# Verb form of "must needs"

Tags: infinitives, verb-forms, archaic-language

> Then touching the shoulder of a townsman who stood near to him, he addressed him in a formal and courteous manner:
>
> "I pray you, good Sir," said he, "who is this woman? -- and wherefore is she here set up to public shame?"
>
> "You must needs be a stranger in this region, friend," answered the townsman, looking curiously at the questioner and his savage companion, "else you would surely have heard of Mistress Hester Prynne and her evil doings. She hath raised a great scandal, I promise you, in godly Master Dimmesdale's church. "

As far as I know we always use first form of the verb after "must". For instance: "You must go". We never say "You must goes". Also, we never use -s/es with a verb that comes with "You". What are the circumstances in which writer has used "needs" after "You must" in "You must needs to be a stranger in this region."?

Comment: This is from Nathaniel Hawthorne's *The Scarlet Letter*, no?  That book is set around the year 1650; the English is very archaic by modern standards.  [There's a discussion of "must needs" at English.stackexchange here.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34788/explanation-of-must-needs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Needs* here is not a verb but the noun *need* = "necessity"; the *-s* is the genitive suffix which in archaic Englishes might express an adverbial sense, so the word *needs* may be regarded as an adverb. (Note that *The Scarlet Letter* is set in the middle of the 17th century, and the dialogue often employs the language of that period, such as *hath*.) In this case *needs* means "of necessity, necessarily".

A few such constructions have survived into contemporary English. For instance:

> *He sleeps days and works nights* meaning he sleeps during the day and works at night

And the same construction lies behind *once, twice, thrice*, though it's concealed in the modern spelling with ‹c› for ‹s›.

EDITED TO ADD, from the first edition of the [*Oxford English Dictionary*](http://archive.org/stream/oed6barch#page/n907/mode/2up):

[image]

Comment: I would appreciate if you give me a proper reference of the meaning of "needs" : Necessarily or of necessity. User3235770 says it means "indeed". Now I am a bit confused, what exactly is the meaning of "needs" ?

Comment: @Amn There you go. See particularly **c.**

Comment: It's a noun, or is it an adverb?

Comment: well, I really did fumble that edit commentary. To me, the word *ADDED* meant that the word or definition had been *added* to the OED. Whether this is even technically possible for that edition of the OED, I don't know, but it was confusing (something similar is said of newer definitions that have been adde to the OED online). I used 'EDITED TO ADD' (although [some people dislike it](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/3iv8mh/why_do_people_sometimes_post_eta_when_they_edit_a/)). Perhaps the simplest thing to do is put 'EDIT'.

Comment: @StoneyB please confirm is "needs" an archaic adverb or an obsolete adverb? Considering it as an archaic word, can I use it in my writing to add a bit of spice of old-fashioned English.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Thanks. I will take care to be less ambiguous in the future!

Comment: @Amn  Uses with *must* and *will* lasted into the 19th century, but are very rare today. You will occasionally find *must needs* in written works, particularly those dealing with theology and philosophy and *needs must* survives in the subjectless proverb "Needs must when the devil drives" and phrases deriving from that. Uses with any other verb seem to have ended about the middle of the 17th century.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks, so it concludes that it is an "obsolete" adverb.

Answer (score -2):

'you must needs be' is an archaic form of 'you must indeed be', and I don't know of any strict rules that govern its use. I'd venture to say the expression is no more in current use than 'wherefore is she' instead of 'why is she'.

Comment: Not, I think, *indeed* but *necessarily*.

Comment: @user3235770 since I am a bit confused between two different interpretations of "needs" :indeed and necessarily, could you give me a proper reference, please?

Comment: @Amn Since _you must needs be_ is **not** an archaic form of _you must indeed be,_ and since there is no connection at all between _needs_ and "in deed," you will have a very long wait for even an _improper_ reference.